# Javascript window.onload within for Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, delay, intervals, pageload

How do I delay myFunc from initiating till openPage is fully loaded?

As it is in a loop, `http://www.example.com/3/exam` is loaded, then myFunc is executed. Instead, I would like myFunc to execute after each iteration but only after each page has been loaded.

i.e.

```
examplewebsite/1/exam
```

then execute myFunc when page has fully loaded

```
examplewebsite/2/exam
```

then execute myFunc when page has fully loaded

```
examplewebsite/3/exam
```

then execute myFunc when page has fully loaded

Below is my code.

```
var ii;
for (ii = 0; ii <= 2; ii += 1) {

function openPage() {
    "use strict";
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/' (ii + 1) + '/exam';
}

openPage();
window.onload = myFunc();
}
```

Comment: you can use `setInterval(function, delay)`

Comment: doesn't seem to be working and I am getting an error.
setInterval(myFunc(), 1000);

Comment: try jquery document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
}, false);

Comment: Each time you set `window.location`, your entire page is wiped out and reloaded.

Comment: that's exactly what I want

Comment: When he says your page is wiped out that INCLUDES any JavaScript... You can't continue executing your JavaScript after you have changed pages.  You could show another page within an iframe or a popup window but using the same window without a container is not possible.

Comment: okay thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
  //Add your urls here
        var urls = ["http://www.howstuffworks.com", "http://example.com","http://www.rgukt.in"];
        var i = 0;
        function loadIframe(url)
        {
      $('#iframe').load(function(){
       //Call your function which you wanted to load after load end
    i=i+1;
    if(i<=2){
     loadIframe(urls[i]); 
    }
    
   });
            $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
        }

        loadIframe(urls[i]); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it didn't work for some reason but I went about things another way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As @torazaburo has pointed out in comments, when ever you change `window.location`, you page will refresh. This means all your variables will too. So will for loop.

If you want to open different pages is loop after a delay, you can try something like this:

Iterator is getting reset due to refresh. But you have this value in URL. Fetch it and use it.

#### Code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Window loaded");
  setTimeout(gotoNextPage, 3000);
}

function gotoNextPage() {
  // Location.pathname will return "/1/exam"
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  
  // for Demo purpose only
  path = "/1/exam";
  
  var pageID = path.split('/')[1];
  var url = 'http://www.example.com/' + (parseInt(pageID) + 1) + '/exam';
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = url;

  // window.location = url;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Also when you did this `setInterval(muFunc(),1000)`, you got error because `myFunc()` will execute function. You should try `setInterval(myFunc, 1000)` instead.

Also for your scenario, I would recommend to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Also note that value fetched from url will be string and doing `pageID + 1` would concatenate and not add. You should use `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested in an answer, I went about the issue a different way.

This was done by opening the url in a new window and attaching the variable to the url itself, which I then called from the opened window. Then closed the window.

i.e. window.open(URL + '?' + myVar);

It was then retrieved in the browser window by window.location.href.split('?')[1];

and closed with window.close();